# Inconsistent template instance - Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I have a `game` template which is included in a table like this:

```
<table class="games-table">
   {{#each publisher}}
   <tr id="{{_id}}" class="publisher-row">
      <td class="publisher">
         {{> publisherTemplate}}
      </td>
      <td class="shooter">
         {{#each gamesType '1'}}
         {{> game}}
         {{/each}}
      </td>
      <td class="adventure">
         {{#each gamesType '2'}}
         {{> game}}
         {{/each}}
      </td>
   </tr>
   {{/each}}
</table>
```

The `gamesType` helper simply returns the appropriate game (`status` attribute in doc, like "1" and "2").

Now the goal is to move the games between the table data fields. When there is only one game associated with `gameType` (and in `td`) everything works fine. But when there are multiple ones, the template instance seems to be inconsistent.

Here are my template callbacks:

```
Template.game.created = function() {
    console.log("created: " + this.data._id);
};

Template.game.destroyed = function() {
    console.log("destroyed: " + this.data._id);
};

Template.game.rendered = function() {
    console.log("rendered: " + this.data._id);
};
```

On first rendering the console output is like this (for two games with the same `gameType` ("2")):

```
created: HN7FL8wKtfxDLzrJM
rendered: HN7FL8wKtfxDLzrJM
created: g2EGnaGW9SP6yhbT7
rendered: g2EGnaGW9SP6yhbT7
```

This is absolutely fine. Now I update the `status` to "1" and the console output is like this (which is also absolutely fine):

```
created: HN7FL8wKtfxDLzrJM
destroyed: HN7FL8wKtfxDLzrJM
rendered: HN7FL8wKtfxDLzrJM
```

But now when I update the `status` back to "2" the game is again in the correct column, but look at the console output:

```
destroyed: HN7FL8wKtfxDLzrJM
created: HN7FL8wKtfxDLzrJM
rendered: g2EGnaGW9SP6yhbT7
```

I don't know why this happens and I am really frustrated, because I need the correct `_id` for my logic in the `rendered` callback. I tried this workaround:

```
Template.game.created = function() {
    console.log("created: " + this.data._id);
    this.currGame = this.data;
};
```

… and then access it in the `rendered` callback with `this.currGame` instead of `this.data`. The problem with this approach is that this does not work for the other game in the same column (because  `this.currGame` is in a stale state).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
Here is the `gameType` helper:

```
gameType: function(type) {
   return Games.find({publisherId: this._id, status: type});
}
```

and here is how I update `status`:

```
Games.update({_id: "HN7FL8wKtfxDLzrJM"}, {$set: {status: "2"}});
```

Comment: Unclear, what is `gameStatus`and how you updated it? what is helper for `gameType` look like?

Comment: Hello, I updated my post and added the things you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I "solved" my issue, even though I don't understand why the template instances from `created` and `rendered` are different, here is my workaround:

1. Added new attribute to `Games` collection called `lastUpdated`
2. Added the package [Meteor Collection Hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks): `meteor add matb33:collection-hooks`
3. Added collection hook *(1)*.
4. Updated `gameType` helper *(2)*.

*(1)*:

```
Games.before.update(function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier, options) {
        modifier.$set = modifier.$set || {};
        modifier.$set.lastUpdated = new Date();
});
```

*(2)*:

```
gameType: function(type) {
    return Games.find({publisherId: this._id, status: type}, {sort: {lastUpdated: -1}});
}
```